# Locate the last non-empty cell so far in a sibling column

Tags: google-sheets

I am working on a progress tracker with Google sheets. I have 2 tables as in below screenshot. On the right table, the number of subtasks per each task must be auto-populated based on data from left table.

I'm looking for the expression that would somehow calculate the `subtask count` with the ensemble below. The approach I'm thinking is to - for every subtask, locate the last non-empty `task_id` cell so far, which can be used for aggregation.

[image]

---

### What I've tried:

The temporary workaround I did is to add task_id for all subtasks and a `countif` formula for count

```
=ArrayFormula(if(isblank(D2:D), "", countifs(B2:B, "<>", A2:A, "="&D2:D)))
```

It works but I don't feel like repeating the task_id for every subtask since its a chore.

[image]

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear contents of range D:E and try in D1

```
=query(ArrayFormula(if(isblank(B2:B),, 
  vlookup(row(A2:A),
   filter({row(A2:A),A2:A},len(A2:A)),2))), 
 "Select Col1, Count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label Col1 
 'task_id', Count(Col1) 'Subtask count'", 0)
```

and see if that works?

[image]

Comment: Wow, that works like magic. Im gonna try to understand now.
+1 for the solution without app script.